# AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'get_file' errot occured using efficientnet and karas

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, efficientnet

[Error occur with karas and using EfficientNet[This is the error i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXdFm.png) ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH0eJ.png)

I tried: -
import tensorflow.python.keras.utils as generic_utils
installed segmentation-models also

Answer (score 0):

If your TensorFlow version is 2.7, then please downgrade it to 2.6.0 for `efficientnet` package to work:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.6.0
!pip install keras~=2.6.0
```

Otherwise, you can use efficientnet from tensorflow applications. Please refer: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/efficientnet